# iphone sdk textbox

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm learning programming iphone app. i need some help making a scrollable textbox with a image background. like the ipod music player with lyrics. thx

Comment: Which part do you need some help with? Do you have some code you can show?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a UITextView with its background color to [UIColor clearColor]. You can then place a UIImageView underneath that to achieve what you are looking for.